# How to Ignore error log with specific message?

Tags: java, logging, error-handling

I want to hide an ERROR log in console, I tried to add this in logback.xml file :

```
<logger name="package.client" level="error" additivity="false" />
```

but this hide all the error logs from the class, so my problem is, How to hide ERROR log with a speceifc message?

The log I want to hide :

```
15:30:06.548 ERROR SearchClient - Status: 404 NOT_FOUND  URL : http://localhost:8888/client/search/
```

Message:

Comment: this should be able to help you out. It'll require a change in your code, though: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html

Comment: Why do you want to hide it in the first place? If it's not that important wouldn't it make more sence to turn that log into a warning or lower?

Comment: Another approach if the client supports it - inject a hook/interceptor in the client to not log a 404.

Comment: @Thomas, We retrieving all the error logs and put them in something like Monitor System, in my case I want to hide this specific error message in xml file, And no I can not change it to another log type